# Assigning to variables depending on choice made in dialog

Tags: gui-construction, core-language

I want to set some global variables depending on which control object I select (the gui interaction should be modal).

Here is my example code:

```
set1Settings[ n_] := Module[
   {},
   a = 1;
   b = 1;
   c = 1;
   ];

set2Settings[ n_] := Module[
   {},
   a = 2;
   b = 2;
   c = 2;
   ];

return = ChoiceDialog["Select data set", {"set1" -> 1, "set2" -> 2}];
If[return == 1, set1Settings[1], set2Settings[2]];
{a, b, c}
```

[image]

As you see the argument of functions is in principle not necessary.

How would you solve this?

Comment: @Nasser: yes it works, but the solution is not very nice ... is there another way to do that what I want?

Comment: I am little confused by what you want. May be this? `setSettings[n_] := Module[{},
   If[n == 1,
    a = 1;
    b = 1;
    c = 1
    ,
    a = 2;
    b = 2;
    c = 2
    ]
   ];

return = ChoiceDialog["Select data set", {"set1" -> 1, "set2" -> 2}];
setSettings[return];
{a, b, c}`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### Edit

I would write

```
settings[1] := (a = 1; b = 1; c = 1)
settings[2] := (a = 2; b = 2; c = 2)
```

Then when I evaluate

```
settings @ ChoiceDialog["Select data set", {"set1" -> 1, "set2" -> 2}];
{a, b, c}
```

and click on the set1 button, I get

> `{1, 1, 1}`

but when I click on the set2, I get

> `{2, 2, 2}`

exactly as expected.

#### Update

This update has been made to address an issue raised in the comments section.

The function `settings` defined above works like any other mathematica function that is stored as a down-value. See[`DownValues`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DownValues.html).

When a function with multiple down values (such as `settings`) is evaluated Mathematica decides which down value to use by treating the expression on the lefthand side of the definition as a *pattern* and looks for a match. Since `settings[1]` obviously matches itself and likewise for `settings[2]`, whenever one these expressions is evaluated, their respective righthand side is evaluated. Most of time the argument values from the lefthand side are substituted into the righthand side, but in this case that step is skipped because it is unnecessary. `settings` sole argument is only used as a discriminator.

Comment: This is great ... I have not seen such a function definition before. So you are defining a function called settings immediately with a value 1 or 2. How does this works?

Comment: @mrz. I have addressed the issue you bring up in an update to my answer.

Comment: Thanks a lot also for the explanation.